# Windows 7 print dialog blocks/waits several seconds on CUPS/IPP-client based printer

Tags: windows-7, printing, cups, delay

I have configured Windows 7 (x64) to use a HP LJ 4000T-series printer managed by CUPS (Linux).

The problem is that opening the print dialog from any application takes ages for no apparent reason.

After the long wait is over, it prints normally and everything is well.

It's as if an IPP-request somehow times out after a while...
Perhaps it tries to get the printer status?

Makes me think of the 'old days' when one was able to disable bidirectional traffic between the host and the printer if your printer cable had no support for that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is quite unexpected: the solution is to change an Internet Explorer setting (!)

1. Open Internet Explorer.
2. Go to (menu) `Tools` → `Internet Options`
3. Navigate to the `Connections` tab
4. Choose `LAN Settings...`
5. Disable the setting called `Automatically detect settings`

Comment: It's no surprise that this got downvoted, given the how weird the solution looks. But hey ,YMMV.